# width specify in px or not changes canvas behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a rectangle by dragging mouse, basically follow this [tutorial](http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/javascript/draw-a-rectangle-using-the-mouse-on-the-canvas-in-less-than-40-lines-of-javascript/).

However, I found that if I specify the canvas dimension in `px`, it will not work. In contrast, if I use this html, this works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>drag a rectangle</title>

  <style>
    #cvs {
      width: 500;
      height: 500;
      border: 1px solid #666;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="cvs"></canvas>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var rect = {};
    var drag = false;

    var mouseDown = function(e) {
        rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        console.log(rect.startX + ' ' + rect.startY);
        drag = true;
    };

    var mouseUp = function(e) {
        drag = false;
    };

    var draw = function() {
        ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    };

    var mouseMove = function(e) {
        if (drag) {
            rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
            rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
            console.log(rect.w + ' ' + rect.h);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            draw();
        }
    };

    function init() {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    }

    init();
});
```

It works fine. However, if I specify the dimension in `px`, i.e.,

```
#cvs {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

The mouse location and the rectangle no longer align. Also, the dimension in the viewport is also different. I suppose it's a fundamental question, but what is the difference between specify the `px` or not? And how does that influence my drag rectangle behavior?

Tested locally on the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the size of your canvas, use the canvas element attributes `width` and `height`.

```
<canvas width="400" height="300">Not supported</canvas>
```

When the page loads the canvas size is set to it's `width` and `height`. If `style.width` and/or `style.height` are set, the canvas will scale to fit the dimensions specified in these styles.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9bheb/5/) is an example.

So now about your question. As I wrote above when you set `style.width` and `style.height` as:

```
#cvs {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

The width and height will apply and the canvas will scale it's size, so the point with coordinates `(x, y)` won't appear where you expect. For example, if you try to draw a point with coordinates `(500, 500)` you probably won't see it at all, because simply your canvas coordinate system's dimensions are less than that. When you don't specify `px` you simply don't provide valid width and height and your style does not apply correctly so your canvas is not scaled and everything works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is about what's the difference between `400px` and `400`, and how does that influence my mouse dragging behavior.

Comment: So if you scale your coordinates too everything will be fine...except the blur effect (or defect...). Better don't use `style.width\height` in canvases.